# Prevent late arrival at jobs in OptaPlanner vehicle routing problem

Tags: optaplanner

I am adapting the VRP example from the OptaPlanner examples here:

https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/7.23.x/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting

However I would like to prevent jobs from being carried out outside of their time window. Instead these jobs should be left unassigned.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See documentation section **Overconstrained planning**.
Basically, set nullable=true and introduce a medium score to count the number of unassigned visits.

But IIRC chained variables doesn't like nullable=true (many users have run into this), so the workaround is a dummy vehicle, like we did for the RH summit demo:
https://github.com/rhdemo/2019-demo4-optaplanner/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/redhat/demo/optaplanner/solver/travelingMechanicScoreRules.drl